# Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name 'springboot.USERS'

Tags: sql, sql-server, spring-mvc, spring-boot, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to insert some sample SQL data into my Springboot application on run-time:

```
INSERT INTO "springboot"."USERS" (USER_ID, EMAIL, FIRST_NAME, INITIAL_NAME, LAST_NAME, PASSWORD, ROLE, ENABLED) VALUES ('1', 'asdf@test.com', 'asdf', 'asdf', 'asdf', '12345', 0, 1);
INSERT INTO "springboot"."USERS" (USER_ID, EMAIL, FIRST_NAME, INITIAL_NAME, LAST_NAME, PASSWORD, ROLE, ENABLED) VALUES ('2', 'asdf@test.com', 'asdf', 'asdf', 'asdf', '12345', 0, 1);
INSERT INTO "springboot"."USERS" (USER_ID, EMAIL, FIRST_NAME, INITIAL_NAME, LAST_NAME, PASSWORD, ROLE, ENABLED) VALUES ('3', 'asdf@test.com', 'asdf', 'asdf', 'asdf', '12345', 0, 1);
INSERT INTO "springboot"."USERS" (USER_ID, EMAIL, FIRST_NAME, INITIAL_NAME, LAST_NAME, PASSWORD, ROLE, ENABLED) VALUES ('4', 'asdf@test.com', 'asdf', 'asdf', 'XXX', '12345', 1, 

INSERT INTO "springboot"."REQUEST" (REQUEST_ID, DESCRIPTION, REQUEST_DATE, STATUS, USER_ID) VALUES ('1', 'TEST', TO_TIMESTAMP('2017-02-09 08:56:29.722000000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'), '1', '1');
```

**Exception:**

```
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name 'springboot.USERS'.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:217)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1655)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.doExecuteStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:885)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement$StmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerStatement.java:778)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7505)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2445)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:191)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:166)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.execute(SQLServerStatement.java:751)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:471)
```

What am I getting wrong here? What is the true format of the following?

```
INSERT INTO "springboot"."USERS"

INSERT INTO "databaseName"."table" ?
INSERT INTO "dbAdmin"."table" ?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your SQL connection, make sure you connected to the correct server and database.

Comment: Definitely connected.

Comment: @santafebound can you take a risk to try that insert statement from SSMS? under the same db connection? if you connected to the correct database, try to refresh the `Tables` directory, to see if those tables exist, or to double check whether the database does exist on the server instance you connected to.

Answer (score 1):

check if the user you used to connect to database have privilege to this DB.

Answer (score 1):

For SQL server, it is required to provide [database Name].[Schema Name].[Table Name] in query. But frameworks like hibernate usually do not put these details in query. What you can do is to provide database and schema as default to user you are using to make connection to db.

Run a script to create new user who has schema permission.

```
use [Database Name] 
GO
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--create new login in database for schema
CREATE LOGIN [User Name] WITH PASSWORD=Nxxxxxxx
GO

--create new user in database for schema
CREATE USER [User Name] FOR LOGIN [User Name] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[Schema Name]
GO

--grant permissions
GRANT DELETE ON SCHEMA::[Schema Name] TO [User Name]
GO
GRANT INSERT ON SCHEMA::[Schema Name] TO [User Name]
GO
GRANT SELECT ON SCHEMA::[Schema Name] TO [User Name]
GO
GRANT UPDATE ON SCHEMA::[Schema Name] TO [User Name]
GO
GRANT REFERENCES ON SCHEMA::[Schema Name] TO [User Name]
GO
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

If you login through SQL server Management Studio with this user, there also, now you can query directly with table name only.